# List of stable coin projects

Tags: stablecoins

I am trying to list the various stable coin projects on Ethereum. So far I have:

- [Maker](https://makerdao.com/)
- [StabL](https://blog.variabl.io/)
- [Digix](https://digix.global/)
- [EthereumDollar](https://ethereumdollar.github.io/)
- [String](http://string.technology/)

Which did I miss? (I'll update the above as answer come in.)